# Product image not visible in category listing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I did `update m2_catalog_eav_attribute set used_in_product_listing = 0;` to reduce the size of flat table. Now the product image is not visible in category view.

[image]

The image is not being displayed because "Use in product listing" has been disabled for all attributes. I need to enable it again for the specific attribute. But I don't know which attribute. I tried to enable it for all attributes with "image" in its name, but no success.

Which attribute is for the product image?

[image]

Comment: please check my ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question. The attribute for product images in category listing is `small_image`. However, it doesn't allow you to edit Used in product listing in admin pages. So I had to execute an SQL query `update m2_catalog_eav_attribute set used_in_product_listing = 1 where attribute_id = xx`.

Answer (score 0):

pls run command to resize images on frontend:

```
bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```